# How to fix flutter doctor not recognizing Android mobile phone

Tags: flutter

I've connected Android Phone on my mac via USB. And flutter devices doesn't list my Phone.

I have enabled Developer options in my Phone and set up USB via MTP connection.

Is installing Android Studio a must ?

Here's output of 'flutter doctor'

````
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale
    en-US)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set
      ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2.1)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.35.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.```
````

Comment: Have you checked the sha dialog appears in the android device?

Comment: What is sha dialog ? No it doesnt appear ! All that appears is a dialog box asking to share media transfer or picture transfer. And I havent installed Android Studio in my mac. Do I really need to install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing Android SDK (part of Android Studio) is a must. Flutter depends on Android SDK for developing android apps, but you need not use Android Studio as your IDE for flutter.

Or you can just install [android-sdk](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads) if you don't want the complete Android Studio installation.